# Control parameter order in derived cmdlet classes

Tags: c#, powershell, parameters, powershell-cmdlet

When creating Powershell cmdlets in C#, you can derive (inherit) one cmdlet class from another. However, in the PowerShell "IntelliSense" tab sequence, the base class parameters always appear *after* the ones from the derived class. Is there any way to control that order?

Comment: Not really. Command completion rely on the parameter binder controllers, and the Cmdlet parameter binder controller resolves parameter metadata by (indirectly) calling `[ImplementingType].GetProperties('FlattenHierarchy,Public,Instance')` and filtering for the `[Parameter()]` attribute - and `GetProperties('FlattenHierarchy')` starts enumerating direct members before walking up the hierarchy.